# Как преобразовать тип *sql.Rows в int? Golang(Go)

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, golang

Моя цель - создать проверку регистрации. Не занято ли имя, email и тд. Так как я новичок я решил сделать это простым способом. Узнать max id и начать уменьшать этот id каждый раз проверяя не совпадают ли значения. Я узнал максимальный id при помощи команды:

```
Select max(`id`) from `users`
```

Но теперь, переменная в которую я записал это значение имеет тип данных *sql.Rows. А так же непонятное содержимое из #, 0, ",", <, > и других символов.
Уменьшить его не представляется возможным. Как и конвертировать в int. Может быть есть какие то другие способы реализации данной задачи? *Mysql

Comment: Вот зачем тебе этот онанизм? Если что-то (имя, email и т.д.) должно быть уникально, то в структуре таблицы должен существовать соответствующий уникальный индекс, возможно, композитный. При этом попытка вставки уже существующего значения приведёт к ошибке, запись не будет вставлена, а анализ сообщения об ошибке позволит точно узнать, какое ограничение нарушено. То есть достаточно одного запроса и анализа ответа, и не надо трясти сервер и слать гору запросов для проверки каждого значения на предмет его "уже занятости".

Comment: А как это сделать? :)

Comment: Можно просто посчитать, сколько таких есть в базе ``select count(*) cnt from users where name='user3'`` Если =0 то нет)

Comment: Что-то пошло не так, оно не число а "&{0xc0001983f0 0x707a20 0xc0001d2140 <nil> <nil> {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} false <nil> []}"

Comment: Можно его в int переменную запихнуть?

Comment: Думаю, чтобы получить ответ на вопрос, Вам нужно показать фрагмент кода, где присходит обращение к базе и проверка условия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для извлечения данных из кортежа предназначен метод [`Rows.Scan`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.Scan). Итерация по набору кортежей делается циклом `for rows.Next() { ... }`

В вашем случае это может выглядеть вот так:

```go
    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT max(id) FROM users`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var id int
    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(&id)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Max id: ", id)
```

Но в вашем случае `rows` слишком много. Запрос возвращает ровно один кортеж, поэтому можно написать проще

```go
    var id int
    row := db.QueryRow(`SELECT max(id) FROM users`)
    err = row.Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```